# Thunderbird: accept event as USER into caldav calendar

Tags: thunderbird, lightning, caldav

I have a work email, let's call it user@workplace.com, to which I get invites for meetings. I use Thunderbird (currently v78.4.0) as my email client.

I have also set up Lightning in TB to sync with my google calendar in which I keep a calendar for work related things, let's call this calendar *Work*.

When I get an invite and press accept I can choose which calendar I want this to end up in and I select *Work*. The event is added correctly and synced to the google calendar. The one thing that annoys me is that under attendees it shows that *Work* has accepted the invitiation while user@workplace.com is also in the list of required attendees but marked as not replied.

In the Lightning settings I have set Username and Email to user@workplace.com while Location is set to `https://apidata.googleusercontent.com/caldav/v2/<Work-calid>/events`.

Is there any way to make the accept be from the email instead of the calendar while still adding it to the calendar?